# Is interation between two components rendered using React.render() possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of employees in a page. Each employee item has a check box adjacent to it. This was developed using react js. Now for every 5seconds,I need to check and show a number of employees available/unavailable status on the page based up on the check box status of the employees.

`<div id="container">
    <!-- List of employees will be placed here by react.js -->
 </div>`

```
<div id="status-bar">
```

Can you please tell me how both divs can be interacted with each other as I am rendering them separately:

```
   React.render(<ListItems />, document.getElementById('container'));

   React.render(<StatusComponent />, document.getElementById('status-bar'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that the two components can interact with each other without the use of a parent component. I would suggest making a component that wraps the two, something like this (written in ES6 and not at all tested... just whipped up for example):

```
class EmployeeModule extends React.component {

  _countEmployees() {
    // Magic to get employee count here..
    var count = getEmployeeCount();
    this.setState({numEmployees: count});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Count employees every 5 seconds
    this.interval = window.setInterval(() => this._countEmployees(), 5000));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="employee-module-wrapper">
        <ListItems />
        <StatusComponent numEmployess="{this.state.numEmployees}" />
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Effectively what you need to do is have `EmployeeModule` handle the interaction between both components. You can get the information you need out of the `ListItems` module, and set it on the state of the parent module. Calling `setState` inside `_countEmployees` will trigger a call to the `render` function, which will set the property `numEmployees` on the `StatusComponent`, thus updating your Status module.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I think the best and easier way to do it - create store. You can use reduxJS to create store easy. You can also include one block in other and provide your data via this.props.